# HTTPS SharePoint site with HTTPS Provider hosted app - The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app

We have SharePoint 2013 site configured with SSL and we have developed a provider hosted app which interacts with SharePoint list.

If we try accessing the Provider hosted app from the SharePoint site with HTTP there are no any errors thrown.

But whenever the Provider hosted app is tried accessing from the HTTPS SharePoint site(using https address) we are getting below error:

> The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
>
> Stack trace:
>   [AuthenticationException: **The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.**]
>      System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception) +2983172
>      System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +473
>      System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +86
>      System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +262
>      System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +473
>      System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +86
>      System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +262
>      System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +473
>      System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +86
>      System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +262
>      System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +473
>      System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +8530566
>      System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult) +230
>      System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) +645
>      System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) +9
>      System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) +87
>      System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result) +1467
>      System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) +84
>      System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) +22
>      System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async) +761
>
> [WebException: **The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel**.]
>      System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +8534156
>      Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute() +58
>      Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder sb) +975
>      ProviderHostedHTTPSWeb.Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +348
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178

We have already added the certificate used for the SharePoint site and the provider hosted app in the SharePoint central admin trusts.

Any idea's how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: If you browse to the provider hosted URL from the sharepoint server do you get an https validation error? What about the other way around?

Comment: @Choggo I do not receive any HTTPS validation errors if I browse Provider hosted URL form the SSL SharePoint site, but get the above error. But if I browse same provider hosted URL from the SharePoint site with HTTP then I do not get any errors also it works fine.

Comment: Could you rephrase? I'm not sure I understood you completely. Also, what type of SSL certificate are you using?

Comment: @Choggo Accessing Provider hosted app form [HTTP SP site] _http://mysharepoint.XXX URL does not throws any error. But if I access Provider hosted app from same application with HTTPS i.e _https://mysharepoint.xxx I'm getting error. SSL certificate used is the Self-signed certificate.

Comment: is the SSL certificate added to the Trusted Certificates of the machine as well? (I saw that you added it to SharePoint's repository)

Comment: @Choggo After adding SSL certificate to Trusted certificates of the machine also the issue persists.

Comment: and has the opposite been done as well? Adding SharePoint's SSL certificate on the App server? Since the error is happening on the App, I guess I should've asked that first. From your app server you need to be able to browse the Https SharePoint sites without a certificate validation error

Comment: @Choggo Yes, from app server I'm able to access the https SharePoint site without certificate validation errors.

Comment: I'm out of guesses then =\ But I'd encourage you to double check the URLs that are being used under ssl, to see if they are browsing with the names supported by the ssl certificate.

Comment: @Choggo Thanks for your support. Yes there was an unnoticed warning for self signed certificate. When I used the certificate issued to my SharePoint site it worked without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution to my problem.

The problem was due to the self signed certificate which I was using for the SharePoint site. When I tried using the certificate issued particularly to my SharePoint site it worked perfectly without any errors.